# How do I delete a customer account programmatically in Magento2 CE?

Tags: magento-2.1, customer, delete

Version: Magento 2.1.0

I run the following codes in my controller and got error:

```
$customer = $this->customerFactory->create()->load($id);
$customer->delete();
```

Error:

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Delete operation is forbidden for current area
```

My code was stopped by the **beforeDelete()** method in Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel.php. It calls another method called **isAllowed(AbstractModel $model)**

How do I bypass these methods and delete a customer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Customer delete operation is valid from admin only. When you perform delete operation, magento check **isSecureArea** is true/false. So you can assign **isSecureArea** by following way:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
 */
protected $registry;

/**
 * @param Context $context
 * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
) {
    $this->registry = $registry;
}
```

Now change your code following way:

```
$this->registry->register('isSecureArea', true);
$customer = $this->customerFactory->create()->load($id);
$customer->delete();
```

Clear cache.